# cross-thread opertion in combobox in c#

Tags: c#

```
catch (Exception ex)\\error
{
    clsLogs.LogError("Error: " + ex.Message + this.Name + " || ImportData");
    result = false;    
}
```

;Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'cmbDeviceName' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on

Comment: Where is combobox in the code? You have posted catch block only.

Comment: Not only a duplicate but also lacking all relevant information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this using Invoke:

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
    {
        //// your code 
    });
```

Comment: thnx it's work...but i use this code in when i click button then one method execute and then parallel progress bar open..when method execute finish then progressbar stop..

Comment: so problem is that..button click event progressbar open but before execute method progressbar finish..any suggestion?

Comment: sorry for being late..is it working now? @user3959583

Comment: but problem is that progressbar first start and then method execut..

Comment: what is progressbar I mean any user control in ur application or any default progressbar @user3959583?

Comment: I cant judge without looking at ur code

Comment: void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {

            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
            {
               System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
               bgw.ReportProgress(i);
              
            }
            e.Result = ImportData();  
        }       importdata is method execute for parallel progressbar..but it's not work..

Answer (score 0):

```
class YourForm : Form
{
    private SynchronizationContext synchronizationContext ;

    public YourForm()
    {
        this.synchronizationContext  = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        //the rest of your code
    }
}
```

and then, when you need to do some thread-unsafe form actualizations you should use something like this:

```
synchronizationContext.Send(new SendOrPostCallback( 
    delegate(object state) 
    {    
        textBoxOut.Text = "New text";
    } 
), null);
```

source [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37642/Avoiding-InvokeRequired)

Comment: thnx it's work...but i use this code in when i click button then one method execute and then parallel progress bar open..when method execute finish then progressbar stop.so problem is that..button click event progressbar open but before execute method progressbar finish..any suggestion?